# sqldatetime overflow c# Ao tentar utilizar type = Date no Razor Usando .NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, .net, mvc, asp

Ao tentar gravar uma alteração de um cliente, o banco de dados SQL Server está retornando a seguinte mensagem:
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

```
View: 
 <label>Data de nascimento:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { @class = "form-control col-md-2", type = "date" })

Model:         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, informe uma data de nascimento")]                    
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

Controller: [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Editar(EditarClienteModel model)
        {

            try
            {
                var cliente = new Cliente();
                var clienteRepository = new ClienteRepository();

                model.Nome = cliente.Nome;
                model.Email = cliente.Email;
                model.DataNascimento = cliente.DataNascimento;

                clienteRepository.Alterar(cliente);
                TempData["Mensagem"] = "Cliente alterado com sucesso";
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                TempData["Mensagem"] = "Ocorreu um erro: " + e.Message;
            }


            return View();
        }
```

Alguém conseguiria me dar uma luz do que pode estar ocorrendo? Ps: já tentei alterar o tipo da coluna para datetime2, como vi em outro tópico aqui, mas não funcionou

Comment: o que tem no método alterar?

Comment: Não tem porque alterar para `DateTime2`, você tem que debugar o código e ver o que está recebendo em `cliente.DataNascimento`

Comment: @LucasMiranda Este é o código do alterar, estou usando Dapper ORM neste caso

`public void Alterar(Cliente cliente)
        {
            var query = "update Cliente set Nome = @Nome, Email = @Email, DataNascimento = @DataNascimento" +
                        " where IdCliente = @IdCliente";
          
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Execute(query, cliente);
            }`

Comment: esse código está bem estranho,ele recebe uma model, instancia um cliente, mas não passa os dados da model para o cliente, faz o contrário, e tenta salvar o mesmo cliente, ou seja, nada vai ser alterado ai! deveria ser por exemplo `cliente.Nome = model.Nome` e não o contrário!

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sim, obrigado pela dica, eu percebi esse erro e alterei. Porém, o motivo do erro era que o DateTime input, na view estava recebendo alguma informação a mais, sendo necessário usar um `Model.DataNascimento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` Após adicionar isso, funcionou normalmente!, haviam alguns outros erros no controller também, mas o motivo deste erro em questão, acredito que tenha sido apenas essa linha mesmo

Comment: outra dia Pedro, não sei se está usando algum ORM (`entity-framework`, `nhibernate`, etc), mas se passar os dados da model que veio da página direto do navegador para o banco e não tiver uma proteção, seu código fica exposto a *"SQL Injection"*

Comment: Estou utilizando o ORM Dapper, não sei se da forma que estou fazendo meu código estaria vulnerável, mas já que me deu a dica, irei pesquisar sobre isso! obg mais uma vez

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, obrigado a todos! irei deixar abaixo o que alterei no código, pois pode ser que ajude alguém iniciante como eu.

```
//Na view: 
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdCliente)
//HiddenFor para especificar para o controller, o ID do cliente que está sendo editado

<label>Data de nascimento:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataNascimento, Model.DataNascimento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), new { @class = "form-control col-md-4", @type = "date" })

//adicionei o Model.DataNascimento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") para formatar a data e enviar //corretamente para o banco

//No Controller: 

 cliente.IdCliente = model.IdCliente;
 cliente.Nome = model.Nome;
 cliente.Email = model.Email;
 cliente.DataNascimento = model.DataNascimento;

//a ordem estava invertida, estava pegando a model e transformando no valor do objeto //cliente, quando deveria ser o contrário para realizar o update. 

//Na model: 

public int IdCliente{ get; set; }
//get set necessário para validação do ID na model.
```